# How to group the rows by two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am doing some work with pandas with a little database, I have 5 rows ID, X, Y, Z and Frame, and I would like to just have a Data-frame where the X, Y and Z are close by a threshold of 12 in each axis and they have the same ID, because probably they are repetitive data or noise. I will illustrate this with a little example, this is what I have:

```
ID,    X,    Y, Z, Frame  
5,  0.,   239., 0, 135  
5,  10.,  242., 0, 136  
4,  12.,  355., 0, 137  
3,  10.,  254., 0, 138  
4,  180., 370., 0, 138  
4,  182., 225., 0, 138  
5,  170., 383., 0, 139  
5,  162., 391., 0, 140  
3,  446., 285., 0, 141  
4,  528., 209., 0, 142  
4,  520., 211., 0, 143  
4,  405., 292., 0, 144  
4,  397., 289., 0, 145  
4,  390., 290., 0, 146  
4,  384., 294., 0, 147  
4,  382., 296., 0, 148  
4,  444., 212., 0, 149  
6,  469., 275., 0, 149
```

and I expect with those values this result:

```
ID,    X,    Y, Z, Frame  Repetitions  
5,  5.,   241., 0, 135    2  
4,  12.,  355., 0, 137    1  
3,  10.,  254., 0, 138    1  
4,  180., 370., 0, 138    1  
4,  182., 225., 0, 138    1  
5,  166., 387., 0, 140    2  
3,  446., 285., 0, 141    1  
4,  524., 210., 0, 142    2  
4,  391.6, 292.2, 0, 144  5  
4,  444., 212., 0, 149    1  
6,  469., 275., 0, 149    1
```

I tried with numpy and pandas a lot of ideas, but the only way I make it work is with 4 for loops, which has a really bad performance.